# Scope using except is not working Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, except

I write Hi, but SO wouldn't let it, so I write longer sentence :) Hi by the way.

It looks like my scope is not working.

I wrote that scope:

`scope :ordered,     ->(field, order) { except(:order).order("#{field} #{order}") }`

but it returns the following when checking SQL:

```
irb >p.levels.ordered("name", "ASC").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"levels\".* FROM \"levels\" WHERE (\"levels\".pie_id = 6 AND (\"levels\".\"parent_id\" = 0)) ORDER BY position ASC, name ASC"
```

NOTE: `position ASC` shouldn't be there

But it works when adding except before my scope...

```
irb > p.levels.except(:order).ordered("name", "ASC").to_sql
 => "SELECT \"levels\".* FROM \"levels\" WHERE (\"levels\".pie_id = 6 AND (\"levels\".\"parent_id\" = 0)) ORDER BY name ASC" `
```

Is except available in a scope ? Or do you see anything that could help me please?

Ruby 1.9.2p290

Rails 3.0.14

Thx

Answer (score 3):

You probably have already figured that you can achieve your goal by using `reorder`. So here's my theory for why `reorder` works and `except` doesn't.

It's important, that methods like `order`, `where`, `except` are handled by instances of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, while scopes, e.g. `ordered` from your example, are delegated by an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` to your model class.

`some_relation.order(:x)` method simply returns fresh copy of `some_relation` with `:x` added to its list of `order_values`. Likewise, `some_relation.except(:order)` would return a copy of `some_relation` with empty `order_values`. As long as chain of calls consists of such relation methods, `except` works as we'd expect.

A call to a scope method, when scope is implemented as lambda returning relation, ends up with merge of model's relation returned by `scoped` with relation returned by the lambda:

```
scopes[name] = lambda do |*args|
  options = scope_options.is_a?(Proc) ? scope_options.call(*args) : scope_options

  relation = if options.is_a?(Hash)
    scoped.apply_finder_options(options)
  elsif options
    scoped.merge(options) # <- here options is what returned by your :ordered lambda
  else
    scoped
  end

  extension ? relation.extending(extension) : relation
end
```

And this `merge` doesn't preserve effect of `except` if it was done only to one of relations being merged. If we merge `a` and `b`, and `b` doesn't have order set, but `a` does, the result would still have order. Now `reorder` works around it with a trick: it sets special flag `reorder_flag` on relation which controls how `merge` carries `order_values`.

Here's my test sample. I'm using `default_scope` to inject order into `Product#scoped`. In your example, order is probably injected into `Level#scoped` by association in `Pie`, which can look like `has_many :levels, :order => 'position'`.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('id DESC')
  scope :random_order, lambda {
    r = order('random()')
    puts "from lambda: " + r.order_values.inspect
    r
  }
end

# in console:

>> Product.scoped.order_values
=> ["id DESC"]

>> Product.random_order.order_values
from lambda: ["id DESC", "random()"]
=> ["id DESC", "id DESC", "random()"]

# now if I change the first line of lambda to
# r = except(:order).order('random()')

>> Product.random_order.order_values
from lambda: ["random()"]
=> ["id DESC", "random()"]
```

As you can see, because of the fact that `Product.scoped` has `id DESC` order, it appears in result despite it was cleared from relation returned by scope.

Here's the list of links to relevant sources:

- [relation's order and reorder methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.14/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L50)
- [relation's except method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.14/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb#L75)
- [relation's merge method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.14/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb#L5), note how `reorder_flag` is used around line 29
- [scope method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.14/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L100)

Comment: Hey, it seems to be nice, I'll take a look soon. Thx for answer

Answer (score 1):

Added scope that u defined in the model

```
scope :ordered, ->(field, order) { except(:order).order("#{field} #{order}") }
```

Tried different combinations and all work

```
a.inspection_serial_numbers.ordered('part_serial_number', 'DESC').except(:order).ordered('id', 'DESC').to_sql

=> "SELECT `inspection_serial_numbers`.* FROM `inspection_serial_numbers` WHERE  `inspection_serial_numbers`.`inspection_master_id` = 1 ORDER BY id DESC" 

a.inspection_serial_numbers.ordered('part_serial_number', 'DESC').except(:order).ordered('id', 'DESC').except(:order).ordered('is_active', 'ASC').to_sql

=> "SELECT `inspection_serial_numbers`.* FROM `inspection_serial_numbers`  WHERE `inspection_serial_numbers`.`inspection_master_id` = 1 ORDER BY is_active ASC"
```

Even if u combine the 'ordered' scope with 'except' in any combinations a number of times, the last 'ordered' scope is used for ordering

```
a.inspection_serial_numbers.ordered('part_serial_number', 'DESC').ordered('id', 'ASC').except(:order).ordered('id', 'DESC').to_sql

=> "SELECT `inspection_serial_numbers`.* FROM `inspection_serial_numbers`  WHERE `inspection_serial_numbers`.`inspection_master_id` = 1 ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Buf it u want to remove all the scopes, use 'unscoped'

```
a.inspection_serial_numbers.ordered('id', 'ASC').unscoped.ordered('part_serial_number', 'DESC').to_sql

=> "SELECT \"inspection_serial_numbers\".* FROM \"inspection_serial_numbers\"  ORDER BY part_serial_number DESC"
```

see  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/except  and  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class

Comment: Hey, it seems to be nice also, I'll take a look soon. Thx for answer

Answer (score 0):

the order of method may be wrong.

it should be write `order("#{field} #{order}").except(:order)`

see [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#except)

Comment: What I want to achieve is to reset the default order condition to set a new order right after. The way you show is removing the order you just set. Then, the query won't have any order condition. See the link you gave. Thx anyway